# How use the conversion settings in Azure Data Factory to convert date formats

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have lookup table that does a lookup on a date field called 'as_of_date' which is used in my copy activity to copy data to the Sink. The 'as_of_date' field is in the following format yyyyMMdd.

Copy activity has the following parameters

```
@concat('XYZ_',
    pipeline().parameters.TableName,
    '_',
    activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.as_of_date,
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'),'.txt'
    )
```

[image]

This will send the data to the sink with the 'as_of_date' field as yyyyMMdd. Can someone help me figure out to modify the above so that the 'as_of_date' field is yyyy-MM-dd

I thought that as I have a Lookup on the **as_of_date** field, I thought I could parameterize it with the 'Type conversion settings' shown here with the following parameter for the lookup

[image]

[image]

Can someone let me know if it's possible?

Just to add some clarification on the question
There are two places where the **as_of_date** can be sourced

1. Lookup activity, see preview
   [image]
2. Copy Activity, see preview
   [image]

As you can see the table contains an as_of_date field which is in the format yyyyMMdd at source. When it is sent to the Sink I would like it to sent with the format yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: Do you mean change formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'),'.txt' to formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'.txt' ?

Comment: Hi @ChenHirsh, thanks for getting in touch. That is not what I mean. I have updated the question with more clarification

Comment: thanks for clarifying, I don't think you can do that without using data flows. Unless you can edit your query to the source and change the format there.

Comment: @ChenHirsh, I'm sad to hear that. All I want is as_of_date to be converted from yyyyMMdd to yyyy-MM-dd as it lands in Sink

Comment: I thought it could be achieved either in Mapping or within 'Conversion Type Settings' that I showed in one of my images in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Convert the yyyyMMdd format to yyyy-MM-dd.
You can use your source query like below

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(as_of_date, 1, 4), '-', SUBSTRING(as_of_date, 5, 2), '-', SUBSTRING(as_of_date, 7, 2)) AS converted_date
FROM date02;
```

I have used a LOOK UP activity to query my date02 table.

```
SELECT as_of_date
FROM date02
```

[image]

Followed by the Copy data activity and in the Source query
I am using my yyyyMMdd transformation and converting the String data type to Date format yyyy-MM-dd.

[image]

In the Mapping the **DateTime format** is
**yyyy-MM-dd**
[image]

Output:
[image]
[image]